# MacBook Wi-Fi automatically turns off and won't turn on again

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, airport

I have a Mid 2010 MacBook Pro, running macOS High Sierra. Recently, the Wi-Fi suddenly stopped working and won't turn on again. I have tried these solutions:

1. Removing AirPort config files from `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration`.
2. Removing Wi-Fi and adding it again from System Preferences → Network.
3. Resetting PRAM while booting.

All of these work temporally, but again after a while (10 to 30 minutes of using Web) the problem re-appears.

Any idea as to what the problem is and how can it be solved?